# Is there a way to make powershell wait for an install to finish?

Tags: windows, powershell, wait

I have a list of Windows packages that I'm installing via powershell using the following command:

`& mypatch.exe /passive /norestart`

`mypatch.exe` is being passed from a list and it doesn't wait for the prior install to finish - it just keeps going.  It builds up a huge window of installs that are pending installation.  Also, I can't use `$LASTEXITCODE` to determine if the install succeeded or failed.

Is there anyway to make the installs wait before starting the next?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Start-Process <path to exe> -Wait
```

Answer (score 8):

JesnG is correct in using start-process,
however as the question showed passing arguments, the line should be:

```
Start-Process "mypatch.exe" -argumentlist "/passive /norestart" -wait
```

The OP also mentioned determining if the install succeeded or failed.  I find that using a "try, catch throw" to pick up on error states works well in this scenario

```
try {
    Start-Process "mypatch.exe" -argumentlist "/passive /norestart" -wait
} catch {
    # Catch will pick up any non zero error code returned
    # You can do anything you like in this block to deal with the error, examples below:
    # $_ returns the error details
    # This will just write the error
    Write-Host "mypatch.exe returned the following error $_"
    # If you want to pass the error upwards as a system error and abort your powershell script or function
    Throw "Aborted mypatch.exe returned $_"
}
```

Comment: Somehow, it proved useless to me (meaning it had absolutely no effect and did not invoke the script) when running this command from my userdata script on aws cloud. I would be grateful if someone could provide an updated answer that will work in my context

Answer (score 1):

Sure, write a one line batch script that runs the installer. The batch script will wait for the installer to finish before returning. Call the script from PowerShell which will in turn wait for the batch script to finish.

If you have access to how `mypatch` is written, you could have that create some random file when it completes that PowerShell can check for its existence in a while loop and just sleeps while the file doesn't exist.

If you don't, you could also have that batch script create a dummy file when the installer completes.

Yet another way, though probably the worst of all of these is to just hard-code a sleep timer (start-sleep) once you call the installer.

EDIT just saw JensG's answer. Didn't know about that one. Nice