# Block Powershell while executing External Command

Tags: powershell, synchronization, block

When you call an external .exe command, how do you make PowerShell block until the external ends?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make powershell wait for an install to finish?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410644/is-there-a-way-to-make-powershell-wait-for-an-install-to-finish)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Start-Process` with the `-Wait` parameter.

```
Start-Process -FilePath ipconfig.exe -ArgumentList '/?' -Wait;
```